# can i start two virtual devices at the same time in genymotion? and if i can what are the pros and cons of it?

Tags: android, virtualbox, virtual-device-manager

I am developing an app in android and going through fragments currently, so for that i need to check the app in mobile device and tablets separately and for that i have to start the virtual devices one by one , so is there any option to start two virtual devices at the same time and if it is there what are the positives and negatives of it?

Comment: Of course you can. Pros and cons depends how you gonna use it. In your case no need to have two virtual device to test app.